# No store/index.js file in nuxt project

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I make first steps in nuxtjs ander after creation of a new project I found
only store/README.md file in store subdirectory, but not
store/index.js file as I expected

Here 
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store
I read :

> We don't need to install vuex since it's shipped with Nuxt.js.

I wonder can I to add vuex to my manually and how?

I tried next successfull command :

```
 npm install --save vuex
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})                                                                           

+ vuex@3.1.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
updated 1 package and audited 10468 packages in 7.48s                                                                                                                                                                                        
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

But now file store/index.js anyway? Which is the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't install vuex on the side of nuxt. And for the `index.js` file, you can just create your own empty one, or put your stores in that one :)

Comment: I expected that file to be created by default. No?  Sure I can create it. Must it be referenced in some app config ?

Comment: No it isn't created by default for some reason, and you don't need to reference it anywhere

Comment: But Here : https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/  I read : 1) Import Vuex,
2) Add the store option to the root Vue instance.    Please clarify in which place have I to make 2) , if I have

Comment: You should just pay attention to the modules mode, where you create every module in a new `.js` file, which is automatically imported into vuex with nuxt. But you need at least an empty `index.js` file to "activate" it. That index file can also be used for a "global" store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After recreating project I found that axios was not added to my project(but I added in wizard). Also there were store, despite what I read in docs, so I had ro run :

```
npm install @nuxtjs/axios
...
npm install --save store
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create it in root/store/index.js